# Create knockout component for table with dynamic fields

Tags: templates, components, knockout-3.0, xmltable

I am trying to create a knockout component for table with dynamic rows and columns. Requirement is both and rows and columns can have controls. Something like this -

```
                    <dynamic-table params="data: item">
                        <header-template>
                           <label>Column1</label>
                            <label>Column2</label>
                            <label>Column3</label>
                            <a href="#">Column 4</a>
                        </header-template>
                        <body-template params="showButtons: ['Edit', 'Delete']">
                            <label>FieldValue0</label>
                            <label>FieldValue1</label>
                            <label>FieldValue2</label>
                            <label>FieldValue3</label>
                            <input type="text" value="FieldValue4"></input>
                        </body-template>
                    </dynamic-table>
```

The approach I am thinking of is creating a separate templates for header and body with in ko component. `$componentTemplateNodes` might help me here but I couldn't figure out a way how I can use it. Any samples on this will be highly useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x311446u/1/)

HTML:

```html
<dyno-table params="headerData: { title: title }, rowData: rows">
  <header-template>
    <h2>HELLO! <span data-bind="text: title"></span></h2>
  </header-template>
  <row-template>
    <div>Name: <span data-bind="text: name"></span>, Age: <span data-bind="text: age"></span></div>
  </row-template>
</dyno-table>

<template id='dyno-table-template'>
  <!-- ko template: { nodes: headerNodes, data: headerData } -->
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko template: { nodes: rowNodes, foreach: rowData } -->
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko template: { nodes: footerNodes, data: footerData } -->
  <!-- /ko -->
</template>
```

JavaScript:

```js
ko.components.register("dyno-table", { 
  viewModel: { createViewModel: createViewModel },
  template: { element: 'dyno-table-template' }
});

function createViewModel(params, componentInfo) {
  var headerNodes = getChildNodes(componentInfo.templateNodes, 'header-template'),
    rowNodes = getChildNodes(componentInfo.templateNodes, 'row-template'),
    footerNodes = getChildNodes(componentInfo.templateNodes, 'footer-template');

  return {
    headerNodes: headerNodes,
    headerData: params.headerData,
    rowNodes: rowNodes,
    rowData: params.rowData,
    footerNodes: footerNodes,
    footerData: params.footerData
  };
}

function getChildNodes(allNodes, tagName) {
    var lowerTagName = tagName.toLowerCase(),
    node = ko.utils.arrayFirst(allNodes, function(node) { return node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() === lowerTagName; }),
    children = (node ? node.childNodes : null);

  return children;
}

var model = {
  title: ko.observable('A TABLE!'),
  rows: ko.observableArray([
    { name: ko.observable('Max'), age: ko.observable(12) },
    { name: ko.observable('Max2'), age: ko.observable(13) },
    { name: ko.observable('Max3'), age: ko.observable(14) },
    { name: ko.observable('Max4'), age: ko.observable(15) },
    { name: ko.observable('Max5'), age: ko.observable(16) },
    { name: ko.observable('Max6'), age: ko.observable(17) },
  ]),
  farewell: ko.observable('Farewell!')
};

ko.applyBindings(model);
```

It's just something I knocked up while considering a similar problem to what you were looking to solve. Depending on your usage it may work for you.

A couple of things to note:

1. You cannot start a tag in the header and close it in the footer like one might want if using it to create a real table. There're probably solutions for that issue but this was just a quick attempt.
2. May not support missing data/templates etc, but you can customize as required.
3. Uses the child nodes of the `-template` elements, not the nodes themselves. Obviously can be modified as necessary.